# Why am I getting the error 1064 (42000) while importing using MariaDB/“mysql shell”?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, virtual-machine, mariadb

Whenever I try import a database.csv, I get this:

http://prntscr.com/eo5eyg

Syntax error at line 1.

I typed

> mysql -u root tatoeba3 < tatoeba_database.sql

tatoeba3 is the database file (.csv)
tatoeba_database.sql is the "final destination"

Alsom **where** should I put tatoeba3? For now, it's at

> C:\xampp\htdocs\tatoeba2

I'm doing according the following: https://github.com/Tatoeba/tatoeba2/wiki/How-to-install-Tatoeba

`MariaDB [(none)]> mysql -u root tatoeba3 < tatoeba_database.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mys
ql -u root tatoeba3 < tatoeba_database.sql' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]`

Also, I'm getting this:

`MariaDB [(none)]> use tatoeba3;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tatoeba3'
MariaDB [(none)]>`

Comment: `mysql -u root tatoeba3 < tatoeba_database.sql;` should be run from the command line, not from inside the mysql tool.

Comment: @fvu how could I do this?

Comment: Instead of starting mysql without command line parameters as you do, you start it with the appropriate command line parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I'm "too newbie". What would be they, @fvu?

Comment: `mysql -u root tatoeba3 < tatoeba_database.sql;`

Comment: but that's what I did. The steps were 1) open shell in Xampp ; 2) type mysql; 3 type mysql -u root tatoeba3 < tatoeba_database.sql;

Comment: even so I got this.

Comment: no. you started mysql, and on its command prompt you entered `mysql -u root tatoeba3 < tatoeba_database.sql;`. These are two **radically** different things

Comment: The correct sequence is 1 and then 3.  Do not do 2.

Comment: gotcha, thank you!